# Importando dados usando pandas no python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Boa tarde Pessoal!

Estou tentando importar um arquivo csv utilizando o pacote pandas no Python

```
import pandas as pd
names_col = ['AnoInfracao',
'TrimestreInfracao',
'CodigoInfracao',
'DescricaoAbreviadaInfracao',
'Gravidade',
'DescricaoTipoVeiculo',
'DescricaoEspecie',
'UF',
'Municipio',
'BR',
'KM',
'NacionalidadeVeiculo']

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Pasta\\pasta1\\Documents\\PRF_DADOS_ABERTOS_INFRACOES_2015_T4\\PRF_DADOS_ABERTOS_INFRACOES_2015_T4.csv", delimiter=';',header=None, names=names_col,skiprows=1,dtype={'AnoInfracao':'category'})
```

O comando executa com sucesso mas ao visualizar os dados os nomes das colunas estão corretas, mas nas linhas de dados são apresentados somente NaN.

```
 AnoInfracao  TrimestreInfracao  CodigoInfracao  DescricaoAbreviadaInfracao
0         NaN                NaN             NaN                         NaN   
1         NaN                NaN             NaN                         NaN   
2         NaN                NaN             NaN                         NaN   
3         NaN                NaN             NaN                         NaN   
4         NaN                NaN             NaN                         NaN
```

O pacote pandas só importa valores numéricos? Este arquivo possui colunas de dados quantitativos e qualitativos.

Alguem tem ideia do que possa ser?

Para acesso aos dados use esse link http://www1.prf.gov.br/arquivos/index.php/s/sRa6yPSftGN7BMP/download
Dados de infrações Registradas pela PRF

Muito obrigado!

Léo

Comment: Se esses dados são númericos e o pacote pandas "só importa valores númericos" talvez seja melhor ir por outro caminho

Comment: Se você olhar bem é uma pergunta e não afirmação amigo. :)

Comment: Peço desculpa, não reparei, distração

Comment: Sem problema, acontece. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ao tentar executar o seu código, primeiro recebi um informação de erro em relação ao `dtype={'AnoInfracao':'category'}`, então eu o removi para poder executar. No fim, deu isso aqui:

> File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 805, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:8748)
>
> File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 827, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:9003)
>
> File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 881, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:9731)
>
> File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 868, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:9602)
>
> File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1865, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:23325) pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 35

Abri o arquivo `.csv` no *excel* e percebi que ele está mal formatado. Já tem linha com nome de colunas, tem linha em branco, e os dados só começam na linha 4 - se não me engano.

Se você for solucionando os erros passo a passo, é possível que chegue numa solução. Mas, respondendo às suas perguntas:

- O pandas não importa apenas valores numéricos.
- Creio que o problema seja o '.csv' mal formatado.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou verificar. :)

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1